# How to sort an ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<int, string>

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, sorting, observablecollection

I've an `ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<int, String>>()` named TestList binded on a Textbox and I want to sort the collection by `int`. I've tried the following but it doesn't sorted the collection:

```
new ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<int, string>>(
                 TestList .Where(p => p.Key > 0)
                 .GroupBy(p => p.Key)
                 .Select(grp => grp.First())
                 .OrderBy(p => p.Key)
                 );
```

How can I sort the collection? And will the Binding still works?

EDIT (doesn't work too):

```
public ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<int, String>> TestList
{
    get { return testList; }
    set {
        testList = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("TestList");
    }
}

public void Test(int index)
{
    TestList.RemoveAt(index);
    TestList = new ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<int, string>>(TestList.OrderBy(p => p.Key));
}
```

and GUI:

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="0" IsReadOnly="True"
Text="{Binding Path=Value , Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Comment: You query will return the first group sorted by key, what do you want it to do?

Comment: `TestList.RemoveAt(index);` will call the getter not the setter so `NotifyPropertyChanged("TestList")` will not be called. Wire something up to the CollectionChanged event, if you want to notify when the collections changes. `TestList.OrderBy(p => p.Key);` returns a new sorted `IEnuemrable<KeyValuePair<int, String>>` which you are discarding, it does not mutate the list in place. You need to do something like `TestList = new ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<int, string>>(TestList.OrderBy(p => p.Key));` instead.

Comment: I don't know what's wrong, but if I insert your suggestion and delete for example an entry with index 2, the OrderBy function doesn't work

Comment: _"Sorting a KeyValuePair collection"_ and your _"Binding to an ObservableCollection"_ problems are two different questions and should have been asked separately for better clarity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to make a group by. You just need a simple order by.

```
TestList.OrderBy(p => p.Key)
```

Comment: I've I set a breakpoint after your line, my collection isn't sorted an the Property TestList wasn't fired. I've updated my question with some code

Comment: @Stampy what Christos meant is : `TestList = new ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<int, string>>(TestList.OrderBy(p => p.Key));`

Comment: Yes I've tried that and set a breakpoint after the line, but the key (indexes) are in the wrong order. If I delete the second item (index 1), I get the collection keys (0, 2, 3, 4) but I need 0, 1, 2, 3

Comment: @Stampy That sounds like it working corectly, if you have 0,1,2,3,4 and you delete index 1, you are left with 0,2,3,4. How do you expect your new list to contain 1 if you just removed it. Sorting a list won't renumber your keys.

Comment: @BenRobinson I want, that the indexes of the other items decreases by 1. Maybe my question is not cleary. EDIT: ok I'm sure, that my question is wrong. I want to renumber my keys. Sorry, I will accept  the answer

Answer (score 1):

Since your source contains `KeyValuePair` objects, you might assume that the keys are already deduplicated. Hence, grouping has no use. Just keep the `OrderBy` and possibly your `Where` and you should be fine.

```
new ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<int, string>>(
             TestList.Where(p => p.Key > 0)
             .OrderBy(p => p.Key)
             );
```